# React app's require() outputs `[object Module]` after updating package.json

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gulp, create-react-app, react-scripts

I am installing a UI framework to a React app and this framework has its own set of dependencies. After updating my `package.json`, I notice that the framework's use of `require()` is not working.

For example, if we have the following in the React JSX:

```
"url(" + require("assets/img/ill/p2.svg") + ")"
```

it will render out as

```
url([object Module])
```

If the `package.json` from the framework is used, `require()` appears to work:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "5.14.0",
    "@glidejs/glide": "3.4.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "7.1.2",
    "choices.js": "9.0.1",
    "gulp": "4.0.2",
    "gulp-append-prepend": "1.0.8",
    "headroom.js": "0.11.0",
    "moment": "2.27.0",
    "node-sass": "4.14.1",
    "nouislider": "14.6.0",
    "prop-types": "15.7.2",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-datetime": "2.16.3",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-github-button": "0.1.11",
    "react-google-maps": "9.4.5",
    "react-router-dom": "5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "reactstrap": "8.5.1"
  },
```

however, if we add them to my existing `package.json`, this problem starts to occur.

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.5.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "7.1.2",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.0.2",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.3",
    "react-router-bootstrap": "^0.25.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "recharts": "^2.0.9",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "5.14.0",
    "@glidejs/glide": "3.4.1",
    "choices.js": "9.0.1",
    "gulp": "4.0.2",
    "gulp-append-prepend": "1.0.8",
    "headroom.js": "0.11.0",
    "node-sass": "4.14.1",
    "nouislider": "14.6.0",
    "prop-types": "15.7.2",
    "react-datetime": "2.16.3",
    "react-github-button": "0.1.11",
    "react-google-maps": "9.4.5",
    "reactstrap": "8.5.1"
  },
```

Specifically, this problem occurs when changing

```
"react-scripts": "3.4.1",
```

to

```
"react-scripts": "4.0.3",
```

How can we fix this problem so that it works with `react-scripts` 4? Thanks!

Comment: There is an [open issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9992) regarding this but no fix yet. If you had control over this code, you could go with [this solution](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9992#issuecomment-722084620) but looks like you can't because the `require` code is in another library. Could it be that there is a new version of UI framework has this fixed for new react-scripts version?